# Destructuring tuple into another tuple type mismatch

Tags: typescript

As far as I can tell the following function seems like it should be logically sound in regards to typing:

```
function testFunction<A,B,C,D> (a: A, more: [B, C, D]) : [A,B,C,D] {
    return [a, ...more];
}
```

Instead Typescript complains about the `...more`, giving the following error:

```
Type 'B | C | D' is not assignable to type 'B'.
Type 'C' is not assignable to type 'B'.
```

Am I missing something here or is this an oversight in the type checker that would be safe to force the type with `return [a, ...more] as [A,B,C,D];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the type checker does indeed widen tuple types to union types when applying the spread operator. Observe:

```
const foo: [A, B] = ...
const bar = [...foo];    // inferred type (A | B)[]
```

I'm not sure if this is by design or just a limitation of the current implementation. I expect it's actually the latter because any function that expects a `T[]` will *have to* widen `[A, B]` to `(A | B)[]` to fit the type parameter `T`.

Case in point, there's no way to generate a `[A, B]` using `Array.of` because its signature is `T[] Array.of<T>(...items: T[])`:

```
Array.of(a, b);        // Argument of type 'B' is not assignable to parameter of type 'A'.
Array.of<A | B>(a, b); // Fine, but inferred type (A | B)[]
Array.of(...[a, b]);   // Fine, but inferred type (A | B)[]
```

One way around this would be simply construct the result array without the spread operator:

```
function testFunction<A,B,C,D> (a: A, more: [B, C, D]) : [A,B,C,D] {
  return [a, more[0], more[1], more[2]];
}
```

Or perhaps *slightly* cleaner:

```
function testFunction<A,B,C,D> (a: A, [b, c, d]: [B, C, D]) : [A,B,C,D] {
  return [a, b, c, d];
}
```

Comment: Related issue: [Microsoft/TypeScript#27859](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27859)